# Reading HDF5 file that was written in java by octave

Tags: octave

I'm writing a framework to write HDF5 files that are compatible with Octave.
That is, I want that my framework will be able to read HDF5 files that were written by Octave and in a way that Octave will be able to read HDF5 files written by my framework.
I'm using HDF-JAVA, to read and write HDF5 files.
The problem is that Octave cannot read HDF files that I write in java.
When I try to read such file, I get an error:
d=load('check.h5')
error: value on right hand side of assignment is undefined

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [`load`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/load.html) in Octave-Forge:

> HDF5 load and save are not available, as this Octave executable was not linked with the HDF5 library.

Is this the problem you are trying to solve with your framework? Or is it the problem that is preventing you from implementing your framework?

Comment: You can try using the `-hdf5` flag mentioned in the Octave-Forge documentation for [`load`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/load.html): `d = load('-hdf5', 'check.h5')`. I have not tested this though.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the problem. If I create an HDF file that contains only datasets the load works.
(The parameter -hdf5 is not mandatory, Octave can recognize the file type - I tried it).
The problem is that I cannot use only datasets because my framework demand usage of groups(for example cell array of matrixes - for  that I must use groups - as Ocave does).
If i'm using groups then the problems start - loading of file that contains groups failes.